# Objective C: Simplest way of implementing multiple actions in a paragraph of text (like comments)

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, comments

I have been trying to implement a comment engine in my app (UItableView) but have been facing challenges

1) How can I add the comment in the table cell with the format of "user name" + "comment text" whereby the user can click on the username and the corresponding user profile will appear. The comment text will just be a static data in the cell

2) How can I dynamically calculate the height of all the comments which will eventually lead to the determination the entire cell height?

I see that Instagram's comment engine is what I have in mind (see below)

[image]

Can anyone advise me on how I can implement the comment engine like Instagram? I have tried to subclass a UIControl and add a UILabel (as a property to it). But this approach seems a little confusing and inflexible. So any advise on this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use TTTAttributedLabel for this purpose as well: https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you comply to the MIT licence, you can use my [OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel) class.

This will allow you to use NSAttributedStrings with different styles for the words of the label (name in bold and blue, comment in black, for example) and add hyperlinks on the text too.

You can also use a properly configured instance (default font, size, etc) and its `sizeThatFits:` method to compute the size needed for the text and use the height of the returned size to compute your cell height accordingly.

*[EDIT] As pointed by @Simon Lee, be warned that this uses CoreText, which is only available in iOS 3.2 for iPhone or iOS 4.0 on iPad.*

Comment: Only on iPad 3.2 and iPhone os 4.0 +, NSAttributed string came with CoreText first introduced with 3.2 for the iPad and OS 4.0 for the iPhone / iPod Touch

Comment: this looks like this could be very useful for something like the kind of notifications like Instagram uses as well.

Comment: @Alisoftware, thanks for response! This seems to be what I need. BTW can I check if I can customize it such that when I click the label, it will direct me to another viewcontroller instead of a hyperlink to the web?

Comment: @Zhen Yep, I designed it so that clicking on a range of text you defined as a link will call an optional delegate `attributedLabel:shouldFollowLink:` method; if it returns YES or is unimplemented, it opens the link, but you can instead do whatever you want with the link, and return NO to prevent the default behavior.

Comment: @Simon Lee yes you're right, I edited my answer to add this precision :)

Comment: @AliSoftware, thanks for the advise. Your class is a lifesaver for me. Thanks alot!